# Preview previously yanked text before put

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

I know that previous yanks are kept in numbered yank registers, a preview available with `:registers`. However this requires to keep a mental model which yank went where, with these numbers ever changing as yanks happen during editing. Additionally `:registers` is not very helpful while in the progress of editing, it breaks the flow.

Is there a way / a plugin which helps me *while* in

- normal mode when pre-prending a put with a register selection prefix `"`
- in insert mode when pressing `^R`

to preview the contents of the registers?

Comment: I suppose you are looking for e.g. https://github.com/junegunn/vim-peekaboo